# Parameter estimation on exponential distribution from a bounded subset of that distribution

Tags: estimators, exponential-distribution, censoring, truncation

I have a random variable that is exponentially distributed with some $\lambda$. I'm sampling observations from this variable, but I'm limited to observing only those that are less than some maximum value $m$ ($m$ is a known value). In many cases, the event is not observed during the interval $[0,m]$, meaning either it would have occured later or not at all. From this, I want to do parameter estimation on the overall distribution.

I believe the PDF of this distribution should be $\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda x}}{1-e^{-\lambda m}} (0\le x \le m)$ (the denominator just being the CDF of the exponential from 0 to $m$), and from there I can do MLE to get $\lambda$.

My questions are twofold: (1) is this a valid estimation to perform, and (2) is there existing terminology to talk about this sort of sampling (from a subset of the support of the original distribution)? This seems too simple to not have a name already but I'm having a hard time finding it.

In some sense the distribution is right-censored, but with a twist: for samples where I see no observation, it is unknown if $t>m$ or the event would never have occured at all. So the hope is the characterize the distribution without relying on the cases where the event is not observed.

Comment: This is standard MLE on a less standard distribution, hence there is no reason to worry about its validity.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, it's fine. It's a perfectly ordinary thing to do. (That's not to say that there can't be some difficulties of implementation in some cases, but the basic idea is pretty standard.)
2. If you are completely unaware of the existence of values outside some bounds, the distribution is *truncated*. This one is a truncated exponential, specifically right-truncated exponential.

   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution